# How to setup a docker container to run on boot in CentOS 6.7

Tags: centos, docker, init.d

I have a CentOS 6.7 server and I would like to run the docker containers at boot time. The docker service already gets started at boot time.

I would like to run this command on boot time: `docker start my_container_name`

I did some googling and the solution was to use systemd, however, it seems that systemd isn't available in the version of CentOS I'm using.

How can I start containers at boot time?

I tried putting the following script in `/etc/init.d` but when I try to add it using `chkconfig --add my_contaienr_script` I get an error `error reading information on service my_contaienr_script: No such file or directory`

```
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig: 345 99 10
# description: Start my container 
/usr/bin/docker start my_container_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the usual *case $1 in stop, start, restart, status* stuff (you can see what I mean if you look at existing scripts in /etc/init.d (apologies if you're already aware of that), but as it stands your init script is accepted by chkconfig on my Redhat 5 vm so I would expect it to work for you.

I suspect you simply have a typo in your filename or when you're typing the chkconfig command?  If you have pasted in the actual error above I can see a typo: my_cont**aie**nr_script. I can replicate your error if I provide a filename that doesn't exist.